# In Katalon, Test Listners are running for each call TestCase when Actual Test case has couple of Call Test Case

Tags: katalon-studio

I am using Katalon to prepare the UI Auomation test case.

The below is my structure of code.

```
1. Call Login Test Case
2. Call Book Appointment Test Case
3. Call Logout Test Case.
```

I expected that once all three activity completed it should get the status of the Test case but it run Step 1 (Calling Test case) then TestListeners and then Step 2 (Calling Test Case) then TestListeners and finally Step 3 and then Test listeners..

I wanted to run once all the steps completed only.. How to restrict that?

How to use Test listeners when I have multiple call Test case in my original Test case

Comment: Can you please share the test code

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://api-docs.katalon.com/com/kms/katalon/core/util/KeywordUtil.html to mark tests as passed or failed.

For example, you add `KeywordUtil.markPassed("Test completed succesfully!")` (or failed) at the end of each of the test cases.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Now Katalon fixed this issue.